# TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './components/header.js' instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created my first typescript project with the command `npx create-react-app myApp --template typescript`, but I'm getting the error `TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './components/header.js' instead.`. I already looked for this error on the Internet, but I didn't find anything.

I also got the error `ERROR in src/components/header.tsx TS1208: 'header.tsx' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.`

App.tsx:

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header.tsx';
import Main from './components/main.tsx';
import Footer from './components/footer.tsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header></Header>
      <Main></Main>
      <Footer></Footer>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

footer.tsx:

```
function Footer(){
    return (
        <footer>
            <p>Desenvolvido por Priscila Alves, e-mail: priscila.contato@live.com</p>
        </footer>
    );
}
export default Footer;
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Did you try doing what it suggests? Why did you change the build script?

Comment: To use typescript in the project the file extension must be .tsx, not .js. I changed the build script as instructed to do in the documentation https://pt-br.legacy.reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html

Comment: Don't include the extension. You're using `create-react-app`, it will rewrite the imports to "what they need to be" once it does your build step. So `import Header from "./components/header";` etc.

Comment: The extension of the actual file and the import path aren’t always the same thing. I can’t read Portuguese but note that’s the legacy docs. The English version says _” If you use Create React App, you can skip the rest of this page”_  - the template already sets up TS.

Comment: Removing the extension from the import actually solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

this config to your webpack config file:

```
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
}
```

these rules to your typescript-eslint

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'node': {
        'extensions': ['.js','.jsx','.ts','.tsx']
      }
    }
  }
};
```